# How to check if new control is added in NgForm?

Tags: angular, forms, formgroups

I'm new to the NgForm. So [here's the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-77ijko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) & below the scenario...

1. I have an application where use has to enter multiple server paths.
2. All the paths are stored in a *list*. UI populates all the paths using **ngFor*. **By default the list is initialized with a dumb entry**

```
public list: any[];
this.list = [
  {
    path: '',
    port: null,
  },
];
```

So this is how the code looks like

```
<form #serverForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="path{{ i }}"
      id="path{{ i }}"
      [value]="item.path"
      [(ngModel)]="list[i].path"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

3. Each path is a text field & each field is a control
4. Control gets their name by *name* attribute `name="path{{ i }}"` & each control has a pattern validator attached to it
   `path: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern)])`
5. Pattern can be of multiple types. E.g., here user can select one of the 2 patterns from UI

```
<div>
  <label> Pattern Type </label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="patternType" (change)="setPattern(1)" />String
  <input type="radio" name="patternType" (change)="setPattern(2)" />Numbers
</div>

setPattern(v: number) {
    if (v === 1) {
      this.pattern = /[a-z]+/;
    } else if (v === 2) {
      this.pattern = /[A-Z]+/;
    }
    // setting formcontrol pattern validator
    this.serverForm.controls['path0']?.addValidators(
      Validators.pattern(this.pattern)
    );
  }
```

6. As you can see, the last line is to attach a validator pattern to the first control `path0`
7. User tries entering new path by clicking on `Add new entry` button. This button has a method associated with it which will add a new field.`<button (click)="addNewEntry()">Add new path</button>` adds a new dumb entry to the list & a new field comes up in the UI.

```
public addNewEntry() {
    this.list.push({
      path: '',
      port: null,
    });
  }
```

8. When **ngFor* iterates over the *list*, *name* attribute which is unique because of the *index*, a new control gets automatically added to the NgForm *serverForm*

**So what is the issue?**

1. Most important, how to detect dynamically that a new control is available in the form and I should attach a validator to it? I don't want to even hardcode the `path0` in `setPattern()` in **point 5**
2. `addNewEntry()` has no clue that a new control is added which makes difficult to add pattern validator in `this.pattern`. **Because `addNewEntry()` executed before `this.serverForm.valueChanges.subscribe`**

**How to resolve this? Basically I want to dynamically attach a pattern validator to the newly generated control inside the NgForm**

Also [here is the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-77ijko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that you're taking the wrong approach. It is much easier to achieve the result you want with Reactive forms vs template-driven forms as you have attempted to do.

What is great about reactive forms is that they have their own built-in arrays, and you can push new form groups into them with whatever validation you want, like so:

```js
public addNewEntry() {
    const pattern = this.patternValue === '1' ? /[a-z]+/ : /[0-9]+/;

    this.serverArray.push(
      this.fb.group({
        path: [null, [Validators.pattern(pattern)]],
        port: '',
      })
    );
  }
```

[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lqhpsr?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I changed the validator regex because the other regex was for capital letters, not numbers.

Comment: This really helped :)